# R tm/qdap - Get document based on term

Tags: r, tm, qdap

I'm trying to figure out how I could identify documents (tweets in this case) based on a term they may include.

Say I have this data frame (df), which is composed of a list of the screen name of Twitter users and one of their tweets.

```
> df
     ScreenName tweet                         
[1,] "Guy A"    "one random tweet"            
[2,] "Guy B"    "another random tweet"        
[3,] "Guy C"    "a third random piece of text"
```

Well, within this data frame I would like to get the tweets that include a certain term -say "tweet"- and *extract* those in to a new data frame (df2) like so:

```
> df2
     ScreenName tweet                 
[1,] "Guy A"    "one random tweet"    
[2,] "Guy B"    "another random tweet"
```

I assume there must be a way to do it using the tm or qdap packages. But could not find anything and so ended up with this mess;

After cleaning the corpus I convert to termDocumentMatrix

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control=list(minWordLength=1))
```

I then identify in which row of the Term Document Matrix the term I am interested in is

```
t <- as.vector(tdm[term,])
```

Subset - if term has been mentioned more than once

```
t.df <- as.data.frame(t)
t.sub <- subset(t.df, t >= 1)
```

Get document number (row number)

```
t.n <- as.numeric(rownames(t.sub))
```

Create new data frames where t.tw - only including tweets mentioning term and t.o - other tweets

```
t.tw <- tw[t.n,]
t.o <- tw[!1:nrow(tw) %in% t.n, ]
```

Thanks for your help.

Apologies if the horrendous piece of code above has offended any accomplished R users.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. `tm_filter` works just fine if you want to search a term/text in a document. How did you apply it?

Comment: It would be better to spend your time formatting the question in a clear coherent way with a reproducible example and desired output than to post code that you call "horrendous".  If you're using this code to describe the problem the chances of communicating effectively your question and desired output go down considerably.  More specifically, share a mini corpus that looks like your data.  Share the terms you want to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd stay in base for this and use the `grep` function (if you already have a `data.frame`) with the following line:

```
df[grep("tweet", df$tweet), ]
```

Here it is in whole with your data:

```
df <- read.table(text='ScreenName tweet                         
"Guy A"    "one random tweet"            
"Guy B"    "another random tweet"        
"Guy C"    "a third random piece of text"', header=TRUE)

df[grep("tweet", df$tweet), ]

##   ScreenName                tweet
## 1      Guy A     one random tweet
## 2      Guy B another random tweet
```